# trouble installing dependencies on chocolate doom

Tags: python

links i have tried to use to download a environment and dependencies for doom(chocolate) on a raspberry pi b+ does not work, and i am unsure about installing some of the programs manually. do you know any other places to get these dependencies on Rasbian?

Wanting to download chocolate doom i first tried to download the dependencies and came back with a 404 page not found error. After downloading and unzipping the doom engine (ready to install dependencies than wad files and then to run) i came back and tried again.I first looked though a guide in a magazine i had (the APC mag issue 441) i looked on the doom wiki and used a similar link which also failed.i visited the page on google chrome and got a 404 error as well.

i used this

```
 sudo apt-get install libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-net1.2-dev python 
 -imaging
```

in the terminal and got a 404 error not found and then used the link from doom wiki

```
sudo apt-get install gcc make libsdl2-dev libsdl2-net-dev \
libsdl2-mixer-dev python-imaging
```

and got a similar error.

i did not expect to get a page not found error as i watched a friend use the same link 1 day earlier. Instead the expected outcome was s dependencies installed message at least.

Comment: Where are you installing dependencies, have you tried anything in [this](https://www.chocolate-doom.org/wiki/index.php/Installing_Chocolate_Doom_on_Linux) link?

Comment: yes GKE  one of the listed commands is from the doom wiki

Comment: What link are you getting a 404 page error from?

Comment: http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/systemd/libudev-dev_232-25+deb9u4_armhf.deb

Comment: See my proposed solution, if it does not work, report back here with any problems.

Answer (score 1):

First update the local package index with:
`sudo apt update`

**The dependencies:**

`sudo apt-get install gcc make libsdl2-dev libsdl2-net-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev`

`sudo apt-get install python-pil:i386 python-pil`

If a simple `sudo apt-get install chocolate-doom` doesn't work then proceed to try a manual build.

---

Quoting from [this wiki](https://www.chocolate-doom.org/wiki/index.php/Building_Chocolate_Doom_on_Debian) follow the directions below for a manual build.

**Install the Chocolate Doom Source Code:**

https://www.chocolate-doom.org/downloads/3.0.0/chocolate-doom-3.0.0.tar.gz

**Now the Building:**

Unzp Tarball: `tar xzf PATH/TO/chocolate-doom-3.0.0.tar.gz`

Then mount the package: `cd chocolate-doom-3.0.0`

Run: `./configure`

Run: `make`

Run: `make install`

Done.